# Python - how to properly extend classes to modify the operation of base methods

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am using some open-source python code that I need to make a slight modification to. Here is the starting situation.

**Starting Situation**

```
class BaseGatherer:

    def get_string(self):
        #a bunch of stuff I don't need to modify
        return self.my_string #set with a hard value in __init__()

class BaseDoer:

    def do_it(self, some_gatherer):
        #a bunch of stuff I don't need to modify
        string_needed = some_gatherer.get_string()
        self.do_stuff(string_needed)
```

Externally, this would get used as follows:

```
my_gatherer = BaseGatherer()
my_doer = BaseDoer()
my_doer.do_it(my_gatherer)
```

**What I need to change**

What I need to do is two things:

1. Have `BaseGatherer::get_string()` return it's `my_string` with an inserted modification that changes each time it gets called. For example, the first time it gets called I get `my_string[0:1] + 'loc=0' + my_string[1:]`, the second time I get `'my_string[0:1] + 'loc=10' + my_string[1:]`, etc.
2. Modify `BaseDoer::do_it()` to call `BaseDoer::do_stuff()` in a loop (until some stopping condition), each time setting `string_needed` with `some_gatherer.get_string()` which by #1 returns a different string with each call.

*with the following restriction*

- The base code I am using is regularly updated and I don't want to modify that code at all; I want to be able to clone the repo I get it from and only possibly have to modify my "extended" code. It's ok to assume the names of the `BaseGatherer` and `BaseDoer` classes don't change in the base code, nor do the names of the methods I care about here, though some auxiliary methods that I don't need to modify will get updated (which is key for me).

**My Question**

My main question is ***what is the best, most Pythonic, way to do this***?

**My Attempt**

Given the restriction I mentioned, my first inclination is to write derived classes of both `BaseGatherer` and `BaseDoer` which make the changes I need by writing new versions of the `get_string()` and `do_it()` methods respectively. But, I have a feeling that I should use function decorators to do this. I've read up on them a little and I get the basic idea (they wrap a function so that you can control/modify parameters passed to or values returned from the function you are wrapping without modifying that function?; please correct me if I am missing something crucial). But, I don't know how to implement this in the derived class, neither syntactically nor logically. For example, do I have to give the function decorator that I write a `@classmethod` decorator? If so, why?

Here is what I did. It works but I want to learn and understand a) what is the right way to do what I want and b) how to actually do it.

```
class DerivedGatherer(BaseGatherer):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DerivedGatherer, self).__init__() #I'm in Python 2.7 :(
        self.counter = 0 #new variable not in BaseGatherer

    #DON'T override BaseGatherer::get_string(), just write a new function
    def get_string_XL(self):
        self.counter += 10
        return self.my_string[0:1] + 'loc=' + str(self.counter) + self.my_string[1:]

class DerivedDoer(BaseDoer):

    def do_it_XL(self, some_derived_gatherer):
        while(~some_stop_condition()):
            string_needed = some_derived_gatherer.get_string_XL()
            self.do_stuff(string_needed)
```

I would then call it just as above but create derived instances and call their `XL` methods instead of the base class one's.

But, there are problems with this that don't satisfy my goal/requirement above: both `BaseGatherer::get_string()` and `BaseDoer::do_it()` perform a lot of other functionality which I would have to just copy into my new functions (see the comment in them). This means when the code I'm using gets updated I have to do the copying to update my derived classes. But, I am ONLY changing what you see here: inserting something into the string that changes with each call and putting a loop **at the end** of `do_it()`. This is why I have a feeling that function decorators are the way to go. That I can wrap both `get_string()` and `do_it()` so that for the former I can modify the string with each call by looking at a local counter and for the second I can just have a loop that calls the base `do_it()` in a loop and passes a different string each time (it's ok to call `do_it()` multiple times).

Any help with suggestions on the best way to do this and how would be very greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are going to subclass, just subclass. Don't bother with decorators. Decorators are great if you need to apply them to multiple places, which is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks for your response but as I mentioned at the end, my attempt here requires me to copy a bunch of logic for both the base methods `get_string()` and `do_it()` into my new versions (I just left it out here). What I'd like to do is "overload" the base methods without having to rewrite all their logic and hence update my code every time the code I am using. I want to follow DRY.

Comment: A decorator won't let you avoid having to copy code if you have to copy code. Decorators are not magic like that.

Comment: Your subclassed method can do everything a decorator can, only without the additional hassle of having to produce a wrapper function. Your overridden method *is* the wrapper function.

Comment: I thought a decorator could "capture" the value returned by the function it wraps, modify it, and return the modification. That way I could call the base method wrapped in this decorator and not have to copy all that code. The base method would do it's thing and I would just modify what it returns before actually returning. With `do_it()` I thought the decorator could just call the unmodified `do_it()` in a loop, each time passing a new string returned by the decorated `get_string()`.

Comment: Yes, but a method in a derived class can do the exact same thing. A decorator is *extra work* here.

Comment: But doesn't that mean modifying the actual base code? Which means when it gets updated I have to go back and make the modification again? Sorry if I am missing something, a little new to this. I really appreciate your help here.

Comment: The derived class method can call the original with `super(DerivedClass, self).methodname(*args, **kw)`, capture the return value, modify it and return the modification.

Comment: When the base class gets updated the risks of having to update your derived class are no bigger or smaller than having to update the decorator. The functionality offered is *exactly the same*.

Comment: The base class doesn't need modifying, no. You'd be deriving a new class that adds methods by the same name that call the original method, just like a decorator would. You just don't have to use a decorator, that's one extra step that is just not needed here.

Comment: I see, ok, that makes more sense, thank you @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most easily done with plain inheritance, no repetition of code:

```
class DerivedGatherer(BaseGatherer):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DerivedGatherer, self).__init__()
        self.counter = 0

    def get_string(self):
        self.counter += 10
        super_string = super(DerivedGatherer, self).get_string()
        return super_string[0:1] + 'loc=' + str(self.counter) + super_string[1:]

class DerivedDoer(BaseDoer):

    def do_it(self, some_derived_gatherer):
        while(~some_stop_condition()):
            super(DerivedDoer, self).do_it(some_derived_gatherer)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Martijn has explained to you, you can easily call a method in the base class from a method in the subclass.  You can do it with super to insure you get the entire class structure as he shows.  For illustration, though, if you are have a simple hierarchy with only one superclass and one subclass, this is how you can do it:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def xxx(self):
...         return "Foo.xxx was called"
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     def xxx(self):
...         return "Bar.xxx was called and then %s" % Foo.xxx(self)
... 
>>> Bar().xxx()
'Bar.xxx was called and then Foo.xxx was called'
```

Comment: Isn't it better practice to use super, regardless of how many base classes you currently have?

Comment: @Ben  It is best practice to be consistent about it, that's for sure.  Google for "super considered super" and "super considered harmful."  The new super() syntax in Python 3 is awesome; for Python 2.7 it's IMO a pedagogical problem.

Comment: I'd always thought that if you use super, it will properly follow the MRO, yet manually defining which base class to call next would break that.

Comment: @Ben  Yes, if you consistently use super() (and all the classes you inherit from did as well) things work.  Things can be made to work without it.  We did multiple inheritance before new-style classes, and the super() syntax was ugly, and half the time in Python 2 you are better off without it.  That's probably changing as more people use it in 3.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin: I can see that there is a bit of a learning curve, but to call the syntax *spotty* is not called for. It works just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I meant to type something else, and reverted to _ugly_.  Anyway, it doesn't work well if you are subclassing from stuff that didn't use it, so understanding the mechanism is useful, but possibly comes after a more basic understanding that you can call the underlying class(es) at all.

Comment: Yes, you can't use it if `object` is not a base class of the hierarchy. As soon as it is, `super()` is preferred.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin I what you mean - but this just feels like a bit of a step back from something that was designed to solve a problem without any gain. If super actually causes problems in the specific case in which I was using it, that's when I would look to see how to work around without it.

Comment: @Ben  In Python 2, you cannot simultaneously use super() and adhere to DRY -- you have to repeat the class name in every single use of super.  Since super() doesn't buy you anything in a lot of real-world situations, that's a lot of extra typing and scope for error for no gain.  Python 3 is different.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin True - but your current solution is also not adhering to DRY (you have to repeat the name of the base class)

Comment: @Ben -- right, this isn't DRY in the single instance where you are invoking a base method of the same name, but super() needs to be used consistently, so it's not DRY in a lot more cases...